# Threw/Dropped it on the floor

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

A man is trashing an apartment.

Moments later, the man came back into the living room carrying a fridge, which he threw/dropped on the floor.

I feel that a fridge is a too heavy thing for one to be able to throw, so I thought "dropped" would be better to use, but if I use that would it be clear from the sentence that the man dropped it deliberately? And if not, is there another word that might be more appropriate to use instead?

Comment: I agree that 'threw' looks odd. In the context of trashing the apartment, it should be clear to the reader that the dropping was intentional.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can also say

> Moments later, the man came back into the living room carrying a fridge, which he **dumped** on the floor.

which means dropped carelessly.

Throwing indeed implies force, and doesn't fit well here since it's difficult to casually *throw* a heavy object like fridge.

I was thinking of

> She threw back her hair.

which also conveys carelessness to some extend...

Answer (score -1):

---

**Threw**

Threw, as the dictionary says, implies "pushing", therefore, apply some force in the action.

If you want to say:

which he threw on the floor.

Add something more if the sense of "dropped it deliberately" is very important to you.

An adjective:
which he efforless threw on the floor.

Explanation:
which he threw, without commiting to much energy on the matter, on the floor.

---

**Dropped**

As for dropped, it already implies in the definition "let something fall" (let implies concious act, you are separating your hands deliberately to let the fridge fall, you are not, by mistake, dropping it). So you can just leave it like this:

which he dropped on the floor.

---

Someone said dumped, which is also possible, but it depends if you are being a semantic purist (basic word meaning) or there is pragmatics involved (context explaning).

If there is prgmatics involved: maybe we know the person who does the action would never throw something to the floor (because he is very caring), well you can use either.

Use a word thinking ahead about the ideas that will pop up in the readers mind. Maybe threw is too harsh but you like it with an explanation because makes the reader focus more in this part of the text, then go for it. Maybe dropped will get the point out and will allow me to move fowards easily. Go for it. Maybe dumped rimes with a word in the next phrase and you want to give some dopped-doppy-dopper, squishy-acid-lover rimes madafaca, then go for it.

Comment: We use an **adverb**, not an adjective, to modify a verb. But _he threw it effortlessly_ suggests that the man was very strong, not that he dropped it carelessly.

Comment: You're right, maybe another adverb.